# How many non-negative integer solutions are there for $x_1+x_2+...+x_5 = 20$ when $x_1 = 2x_2$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, solution-verification

$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20  $

Where

$ x_1 = 2x_2 $

So basically, I just substituted $ 2x_2$ into $x_1$ and the new equation becomes:

$ 3x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20 $

$  x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20 - 3x_2 $

Now I will replace $x_2$ with simply $i$

$  x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20 - 3i $

Then the equation can be solved for all non-negative $i$ using the Distribution theorem:
$C(r+n-1, r)$ with the general form:

$C( (20-3i)+3-1, 20-3i )$

So for $i={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}$:

$ \binom{22}{20} + \binom{19}{17} +\binom{16}{14} + ... + \binom{4}{2}$

Would this be correct?

Comment: This seems fine.

Comment: Stars and Bars! Plus a little rethinking on the constraint. How can you use the constraint to simplify your first equation?

Comment: Thank you. I was starting to doubt my method and then decided to do something like x2+x3+x4+x5 = 20-2i and then doubting that and went back and forth for about 30 minutes until i decided to post here

Comment: @stuart stevenson  hm.. i am not sure how i can simplify it

Comment: Is there a way I can use the constraint to simplify my equation?

Comment: How many ways can $20$, $17$, $14$, $11$, $8$, $5$, and $2$ each be written as an ordered sum of three nonnegative integers (counting sums that differ only in the order of the summands as different)? Then, add up the results for all of them.

Comment: I just use generating function and let the algebra do its magic if I want to be sure.